# Obtain the balance of erc20 tokens with Polkadot JS

Tags: polkadot-js, evm

I'm seeking a method to retrieve the balances of all ERC20 tokens associated with an account using the Polkadot JS API. I've been unable to locate a specific API call that enables this functionality. If anyone is aware of the relevant API call, I would greatly appreciate the information. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

See the PolkadotJS documentation about how to query Smart Contracts: [Contract](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read/#reading-contract-values).

First you have to initialize the contract.

```js
import { ContractPromise } from '@polkadot/api-contract';

// The address is the actual on-chain address as ss58 or AccountId object.
const contract = new ContractPromise(api, metadata, address);
```

And then call the specific function you want, in your case [balance_of](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/erc20/lib.rs#L83)

```js
const callValue = await contract.query.balanceOf(from, { gasLimit}, addressToQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to know the balance of all the tokens an account has, is there any way to know what tokens an account has? Thanks

Comment: @BrianRamirez no, that's not possible. Since the record of a token's balance is stored in the smart contract, you would have to know the addresses of all smart contracts you want to/have to query in advance. There is a way of finding all contracts an account has interacted with in the past, but it's more complicated than a single API call.

Comment: Exactly, if you know the addresses you want to query is as explanaied. @smm I'd love to know how you can find all the contracts an account has interact with